# How to group voids in c# MEF Plugins

Tags: c#, mef

How can I group voids in c# MEF?

I have the main plugin interface:

```
[InheritedExport]
public interface IHostPlugin
{
    void LOG_WriteLog(string Message);
    void LOG_DeleteLog(string Id);
    void Notifications_SendNotification(string Message);
}
```

Now, on the plugin

```
[Import("IHostPlugin", typeof(IHostPlugin))]
public IHostPlugin HostPlugin { get; set; }
```

and I can call the plugin Void like this:

```
HostPlugin.LOG_WriteLog("Test");
```

But what I want is to group the voids, and call like this:

```
HostPlugin.LOG.WriteLog("Test");
HostPlugin.Notifications.SendNotification("Test");
```

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your best shot is:

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TypeCatalog catalog = new TypeCatalog(typeof(LOG), typeof(Notifications), typeof(Plugin1));

        CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        HostPlugin host = new HostPlugin();

        container.SatisfyImportsOnce(host);

        host.LOG.WriteLog("Test");
        host.Notifications.SendNotification("Test");
    }
}

public class Plugin1
{
    [Export("LOG.WriteLog")]
    private void LOG_WriteLog(string Message) { }

    [Export("LOG.DeleteLog")]
    private void LOG_DeleteLog(string Id) { }

    [Export("Notifications.SendNotification")]
    private void Notifications_SendNotification(string Message) { }
}

public class HostPlugin
{
    [Import]
    public LOG LOG { get; private set; }

    [Import]
    public Notifications Notifications { get; private set; }
}

[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class LOG
{
    [ImportMany("LOG.WriteLog", AllowRecomposition = true)]
    private Action<string>[] Write { get; set; }

    public void WriteLog(string Message)
    {
        foreach (Action<string> action in Write)
        {
            action(Message);
        }
    }

    [ImportMany("LOG.DeleteLog", AllowRecomposition = true)]
    private Action<string>[] Delete { get; set; }

    public void DeleteLog(string Id)
    {
        foreach (Action<string> action in Delete)
        {
            action(Id);
        }
    }
}

[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class Notifications
{
    [ImportMany("Notifications.SendNotification", AllowRecomposition = true)]
    private Action<string>[] Send { get; set; }

    public void SendNotification(string Message)
    {
        foreach (Action<string> action in Send)
        {
            action(Message);
        }
    }
}
```